# Making a hole in a computer touch screen

Tags: touchscreen

I have just replaced the touch screen on my HP laptop.  All works well but the opening for the camera on the new touch screen is offset a bit from the original.  Hence the camera is looking through the touch screen.  Needless to say, the camera is essentially useless.

Is there a way to make a new hole for the camera without going through the entire process of removing the touch screen?

I don't think the various plastic housings and connectors can take another assault.

Comment: For all the work involved I would suggest getting an external camera, they are not that expensive and will save you a lot of grief.

Comment: Pain, great pain...

Comment: Nope. Just chalk it up to the cost of saving a laptop.